# How to use VLC to stream webcam to server then server to viewers

Tags: windows, vlc-media-player, streaming, video-streaming

I am able to stream my PC webcam using VLC directly to viewers. However, my home bandwidth is limited. To be able to accommodate more viewers, I want to stream my webcam to an external server so that my viewers will connect to that instead of my home IP. In effect my viewers will use the server's bandwidth, not my PC's. To illustrate:

`My Webcam >>>stream to>>> External Server >>>stream to>>> Viewers`

Is this possible to achieve using VLC? Or are there better alternatives?

Comment: Even if the viewers are 'streaming' on the external server bandwidth, the main bottleneck will still your own PC ISP upload speed... But what you wanted is not impossible. If you can use VLC on the external server to open up the Webcam stream on your PC, then viewers can connect to the external server.

Comment: I had this idea since I can think I can install VLC to the server then open up my PC's stream from there, then, stream that stream to the viewers. I am not sure why you think my PC will be the bottleneck since it theoretically only uploads to the server, while the server serves all the bandwidth to the viewers.

Comment: Sorry somehow I was thinking you may be on a home ISP line with limited upload.. not sure why I had that thought when I wrote that.